# getting all possible products of five consecutive digits from a list of 1000 consecutive digits.

Tags: combinations

If I have 1000 continuous digits in a list, how many different products of five consecutive digits can I get from the list?

Comment: Thanks, If I remove element 0 from  my list after I have gone through the first iteration, adding each five values  and repeat until my list is empty I will have gotten all values?

Comment: Sorry I was wrong in my first comment, here the right answer: Just choose any digit from 1 to 996 and multiply that number and 4 numbers forward, giving you product of five consecutive digits. Giving you 996 products.

Comment: As for your second question, if you loop through the digits from the first until the list is empty you WILL get all the possible products.